# Retrieve form-data body using tornado on server side

Tags: postman, tornado, multipart, form-data

[image]

As shown in the picture i am doing a mutlipart/ form-data POST from postman and trying to get the body using tornado in the backend. But as per the documentation I have been using "get_body_argument" to fetch the test1.txt file but it doesnt seem to return anything. All I need is to read the contents of test1.txt. I can print self.request.body in the backend which prints entire payload in string format (pasted in the below snippet). But i was expecting get_body_argument to return VALUE i.e. test1.txt when does RequestHandler.get_body_argument(self, name="dev1"). May be i am missing something, can someone please help what i might be doing wrong?

```
b'----------------------------480521028869482153987638\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dev1\n"; filename="test1.txt"\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\nxxxxx\nyyyyy\n\r\n----------------------------480521028869482153987638\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dev2"; filename="test2.txt"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\naaa\nbbb\n\r\n----------------------------480521028869482153987638--\r\n'
b'----------------------------480521028869482153987638\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dev1\n"; filename="test1.txt"\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\nxxxxx\nyyyyy\n\r\n----------------------------480521028869482153987638\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dev2"; filename="test2.txt"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\naaa\nbbb\n\r\n----------------------------480521028869482153987638--\r\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Tornado, uploaded files are considered different from "arguments". You can access them via `self.request.files["dev1"].filename` (and `.body` for the contents).